# What does $\overline\Gamma= \Gamma / \lbrace \pm I \rbrace $ mean?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Here $\Gamma $ is a congruence subgroup for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ .
The definition says I have to consider $\gamma \cdot (\pm I)$   with $\gamma \in \Gamma$ .

Thanks for help .

Comment: The quotient of $\Gamma$ by $\pm I$, i.e., the corresponding subgroup in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$...

Answer (score 0):

When $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on the upper half plane, the linear fractional transformation
$$\gamma = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$$
sends an element $x$ to
$$\gamma(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}.$$
Therefore if you consider the transformation $-I \cdot \gamma$, how does the point $(-I\cdot\gamma)(x)$ compare to the point $\gamma(x)$ for any point $x$?

Comment: I think it is equal  because then you have $(-I \gamma)(x)=\frac{-ax-b}{-cx-d}=\gamma(x)$

Comment: Yes, exactly. So does it make sense my you need to mod out by $\pm I$?

Comment: So under this transformation $\gamma$ is identified with$-\gamma$ ?